# Preventing AIX mount point from writing to root file system

Tags: permissions, aix

Is there a way to make the mount point unwritable? I can't write a script or anything to check, but thought there might be a way to do this via permissions. On Linux you could make it immutable. The problem is that a backup process is filling up the root file system when the mount point fails.

Comment: Why can't you write a script to make the check?  Many backup tools allow you to run pre/post backup scripts that can perform this sort of check (and abort the backup if necessary).

Comment: Its an application level backup unfortunatly. The functionality baked in and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Does AIX let you mount a filesystem over an existing filesystem?  Under Linux, you could do something like this:

```
# mount -t tmpfs -o ro none /mnt/fs
```

So now `/mnt/fs` is a read-only filesystem:

```
# touch /mnt/fs
touch: cannot touch `/mnt/fs/foo': Read-only file system
```

But you can mount something over it like this:

```
# mount /dev/myvg/mylv /mnt/fs
```

And *that* filesystem is writable:

```
# touch /mnt/fs/foo
# ls /mnt/fs
foo
```

If the second mount fails, you're still left with a read-only filesystem.  If AIX supports this sort of overlapping mount this might do what you want.